# How to extract the repeated part of string?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract the repeated part of string using Java regex.

My string is: `s01e04:11:08`

Regex is: `^s(\\d+)e(\\d+)(:\\d+)*$`

Regex is matched but when I'm trying to extract third group it returns only the last part of it.

Expected: `:11:08`

Got: `:08`

Full code is:

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {
        String marker = "s01e04:11:08";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile("^s(\\d+)e(\\d+)(:\\d+)*$");
        Matcher matcher = r.matcher(marker);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a capturing group around the repeat:

```
^s(\\d+)e(\\d+)((:\\d+)*)$
               ^        ^
```

You can also make the repeated group non-capturing, if you never need to get that by itself:

```
^s(\\d+)e(\\d+)((?::\\d+)*)$
                 ^^
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I understood, it is no matter, how many included groups will be in one of the first level group. Or there is some way to get one of nested subgroups of first level group? Something like 2D array indexing(`group[1][2]`), not necessary in Java.

Comment: I found the answer. If we use `^s(\\d+)e(\\d+)(:\\d+)*$` for matching with the `s01e04` we will get `null` on getting 3 group. If for matching with `s01e04:11:08` we will get `:08` - last repeated piece of group 3. If we will use the `^s(\\d+)e(\\d+)((:\\d+)*)$` we will get `""` in first case and `:11:08` in second case. Also, with second expression we can refer to last repeated piece(inner group) of group 3 with index 4. And If we want to disable ability to refer to group 4 we can use the repeated group non-capturing expression: `^s(\\d+)e(\\d+)((?::\\d+)*)$`

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern does not match 1st ":".

Try Using This.

```
("^s(\\d+)e(\\d+)((:\\d+)+)$")
```

`(:\\d+)+` match :dd one or more times.